# MahApps HamburgerMenu with IconPacks icons

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I'm sure it's something to do with the MenuItemTemplate but can't find any code to help me correct the issue.  The icons don't show at all!

I have a Net.Core 3.1 WPF application

I used NUGET to load the IconPacks 4.1 package using [this](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks) as a guide.

In my xmal file I reference it like this; `xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks` because I'm not sure how to reference it otherwise but this works.

```
        <Grid>
            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="EmoticonCool"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
```

but I'm trying to get some example MahApps HamburgerMenu code to work.  It used 'Segoe MDL2 Assets' font to gain images but I want to use IconPacks.  I couldn't get the Segoe stuff to work either.

So the code that doesn't work is;

```
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
                <Grid Height="48" Background="Gray">
                    <!--<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="{Binding Tag}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>-->
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />  ****** I'm thinking this is where my problems lies ******
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DockPanel.Resources>

        <Controls:HamburgerMenu Foreground="White" PaneBackground="#FF444444" IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
            <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Label="Part Info">
                        <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
                            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="EmoticonCool" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
                        <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                            <TextBlock>Part Info</TextBlock>
                        </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="M" Label="Main Menu" Tag="ShowMainMenu"/>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="I" Label="Invoice" Tag="OpenInvoiceMaker"/>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="R" Label="Reports" Tag="ShowReportsMenu"/>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
            <Controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="A" Label="About" Tag="About"/>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
            <Controls:HamburgerMenu.Content>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Border Background="#FF444444" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding ActiveItem.DisplayName}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" CanContentScroll="True" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False">
                        <Controls:TransitioningContentControl Transition="LeftReplace" x:Name="ActiveItem" Content="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DockPanel>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu.Content>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenu>
        <Grid>
            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="EmoticonCool"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Any helpappreciated

Answer (score 1):

For those that stumbled like me on this problem I'm posting the solution I found.

Turns out the DataTemplate was the problem and I fixed it by using this template instead, which makes sense because I'm not using a TextBlock and the Segoe MDL2 Assets font to display the icon I'm using an actual Icon.

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Controls:HamburgerMenuItem}">
                <Grid Height="64">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Viewbox ToolTip="{Binding Label}" Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Viewbox.Child>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Icon}"></ContentControl>
                            </Viewbox.Child>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="16"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Text="{Binding Label}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```